# Hangfire 1.6.22 operation was cancelled then gets picked up by another worker

Tags: .net, iis, hangfire

I have setup a really long running job that can run anywhere from 10 minutes to 7 days. What I'm observing is that the job some how gets cancelled along the way (not sure by what) with an exception thrown.

```
System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled. 
    at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowOperationCanceledException()
    at Hangfire.Server.ServerJobCancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()
```

It then gets picked up by a different worker. What I know for sure is that

- The job did not fail and get picked up again because of retry logic because AutomaticRetry Attempts is set to 0
- The job is still running because according to Hangfire console, it is still processing.
- There are other jobs still waiting for this job to finish before executing.

A screenshot of the current state of the job is below. I'm not sure what is triggering this auto timeout but my current best guess is any restart to the web application on the IIS instance would trigger an operation canceled event. Are there other scenarios that I am missing?

[image]

Comment: What kind of storage, and Hangfire version are you using ?

Comment: Hangfire 1.6.22, persisted in SQL Server. I actually figured this one out. This happens when Hangfire server is unexpectedly shut down. When it starts up again, the job is not considered failed, it actually just gets picked by a random worker again when hangfire server resumes.